# What would happen to a star caught in the path of an astrophysical jet?

Tags: stars, supernova, relativistic-jets

The question pretty much captures it. What would happen to a star caught in the path of an astrophysical jet? I imagine the distance to the source of the jet, and the power of the source, matter most when determining the fate of a star caught in one these jets, so use whichever measurements that make the calculation easiest, but I would like a few scenarios if at all possible (for example a star caught in the relativistic jet of a supermassive black hole at relatively close range, then something like a neutron star's jet at relatively long distance).

When I ask what would happen to the star, I am asking if the star would be blown up spectacularly, or if the stellar material would be stripped away slowly over time, or would the extra energy cause the star to heat up, fuse more, and then go supernova, or would some other scenario I haven't even fathomed be the result? Thanks for any insight that you can provide.

Comment: I can't help thinking the answer is nothing for "long distance", as you'd likely define a long distance as being outside the range of any significant effects.

Comment: @StephenG-HelpUkraine I'd define “long distance” as being at a distance that would not affect the test object (a star in this case) _if not for the jets._ But “test” stars also come in various masses, sizes and degrees of puffiness. Red giants barely hold their atmosphere at all...

Comment: @kkm is correct about what I meant by "long distance". Long distance would be far enough away that the supernova doesn't get it, but still within the range of the jets, if that's even possible.

Comment: @kkm I had a hunch that the type of star would matter, because I was wondering if the jet would turn a neutron star into a black hole, whereas bigger stars, I thought would have its mass stripped away.